# New-Item : Access to the path is denied

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script below

```
$ous = 'ou=office,dc=xxx,dc=com',`
       'ou=shop0,dc=xxx,dc=com',`
       'ou=shop1,dc=xxx,dc=com',`
       'ou=shop2,dc=xxx,dc=com'
$outfile = 'c:\work\userinfo.csv'

New-Item  -Force -type "file" -Path 'c:\work\userinfo.csv'

$ous | ForEach { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ |
    Select-Object -Property CN,`
        DisplayName,`
        GivenName,`
        Surname,`
        SamAccountName,`
        PasswordExpired,`
        mail,`
        Description,`
        Office,`
        EmployeeNumber,`
        Title |
    Sort-Object -Property Name |
    export-csv -Append $outfile -NoTypeInformation

    }
```

Then when I run it, I got error message "New-Item: access to the path c:\work\userinfo.csv" is denied.

What's the cause for this error?

**Update:**

In my case, somehow, PowerShell is case-sensitive....the output folder name is *uppercase*, in my script is *lowercase*, it works after I match them.

Comment: Is it already open? Or in use somewhere else like Excel or notepad. It could just be a simple permissions issue but I would guess you already considered that.

Comment: No, file does not exist, the reason i put a `new-item` there is that each time I run script, I could get an fresh result without previous results. or maybe i just need to change the way I output the file?

Comment: Even I only run `New-Item  -Force -type "file" -Path 'c:\work\userinfo.csv'` I still get the same error.

Comment: @Matt I just noticed that there is no issues if I use `new-item` to create a txt file, but csv file. so `new-item` wont work with csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am bypassing the reason for the error ( of which I'm not sure of the cause.). Another way to get what you want

> each time I run script, I could get an fresh result without previous results

You just need to move the output code outside the loop and remove the append. Pipeline handles the Append for you.

```
$ous | ForEach { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ |
    Select-Object -Property CN,`
        DisplayName,`
        GivenName,`
        Surname,`
        SamAccountName,`
        PasswordExpired,`
        mail,`
        Description,`
        Office,`
        EmployeeNumber,`
        Title              
} | Sort-Object -Property Name |
    export-csv -Append $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

**Noticed something**

You are not calling all the properties you are using in your select statement. That should lead to some null columns in your output. I would update your code to something like this.

```
$props = "CN","DisplayName","GivenName","Surname","SamAccountName","PasswordExpired","mail","Description","Office","EmployeeNumber","Title"  

$ous | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ -Properties $props | Select-Object $props           
} | Sort-Object -Property Name |
    export-csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I just noticed that there is no issues if I use new-item to create a txt file, but csv file. so new-item wont work with csv file?

Comment: I tried your way, it does not work still, I feel it must be somewhere wrong with csv file. It works with txt file.

Comment: what does _not work_ mean exactly? Your new-item code works perfectly fine for me. It even made the folder work with `-Force`.

Comment: Your code,`foreach{} | sort | export-csv` I still get `access denied` message. but if output file is text file, it works on both your code and my code.

Comment: @RootLoop Is _a_ csv file or _that_ csv file? Does it work if you change the name or path to `c:\temp\test.csv` for instance. I still think it might have an open handle somewhere. Consider rebooting and try again.

Comment: It works now with `temp` directory. AND I found why it could not work .....You wont believe it....I dont think in powershell case is sensitive, but on my PC, my folder is `c:\WORK` and in my script, it was `c:\work`. once I changed it to `c:\WORK` in my script, everything works just fine.....

Comment: @RootLoop I didn't think that was a thing but i'm glad it works for you.